# CSS aspect ratio overflowing horizontally instead of reducing height

Tags: html, css, aspect-ratio

I'm trying to use the css `aspect-ratio` property to create a canvas with p5.js. It's working somewhat right. Basically I'm aiming to have it stretch the purple box either as far wide or tall as it can go and then stop growing. When the aspect ratio is vertical it works fine but when its horizontal, 16/9 for example, it will overflow outside the container.

```
<div class="flex w-4/5 h-[90vh]">
    <div
        id="puff-container"
        style="aspect-ratio: {x}/{y};"
        class="outline outline-offset-2 shadow-2xl"
    >
        {#if $puff}
            <P5 sketch={$puff} />
        {:else}
            <div class="bg-orchid w-full h-full" />
        {/if}
    </div>
</div>
```

The problem is that the div that has the aspect ratio is growing to use the entire height but I don't know how to restrict that properly.
Basically I need a horizontal aspect ratio to stay within the defined container (stopping at the options bar) and when it hits that wall it should reduce height instead of overflowing.

[image: square example]
[image: vertical example]
[image: horizontal bad example]